# How to implements _isset magic method?

Tags: php, magic-methods

I try to implement the __isset magic method such as the following code,

Why do I always get an undefined index error? can anyone tell me how to do?

```
class c {
    public $x = array();
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->x[$name]; //undefined index: #1:a / #2:b / #3:d
    }
    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->x[$name]);
    }
}

$c = new c;
var_dump(isset($c->a));      
var_dump(isset($c->a->b));   #1
var_dump(isset($c->b->c));   #2
var_dump(isset($c->d['e'])); #3
```

Why the following code is working fine? I don't understand?

```
$x = array();
var_dump(isset($x->a->b->c));       
var_dump(isset($x['a']['b']['c']));
```

Comment: `var_dump(isset($c->a->b));` means get `a` from `$c` and check if `b` isset on `a`. You would need to implement __isset on whatever object `a` is or fix your __get method to check if isset before blindly returning.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: The interesting question is why the compiler does not run `isset($c->a)` first and after seeing `false` refrain from going further -- which would eliminate the warning. After all, you don't have this problem with plain objects (e.g. remove both magic methods and run the code: no warnings). I guess "because PHP", and I consider this a bug.

Comment: @Jon the reason the compiler doesn't run isset before get is the same reason that it doesn't run isset for any other variable. if I just blindly say `echo $blah;` it doesn't check to see if `$blah` isset before returning it. It just returns `null` and throws an error. And it does throw errors without the methods. http://codepad.viper-7.com/eXba3r

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: You misunderstood me. [It does not throw errors](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HLVCJH) if you have an `isset()` guard, just as you do in your code.

Comment: @Jon If you check isset in `__get` and return null if not isset internally, you get no errors. http://codepad.viper-7.com/xA6b5p

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Which is my whole point: why does the compiler *make* you do this? If it utilized the `__isset` *that you have already written* you could save the trouble.

Comment: @Jon Why does it require you to check any variables? why don't they just all return null and not throw an error? In the example `$c->a->b` he is not calling isset on `$c->a`, he is getting `$c->a` and checking `b` on that.

Comment: Jonathan, again, *yes I know that*. But if `$c = new stdClass` *it does not work like you describe* because if it got `$c->a` first then `isset($c->a->b)` would warn, and *it does not* (again, for an `stdClass`). So -- why does it work one way when A and a different way when B? Wouldn't it be preferable if its observable behavior were identical in both cases?

Comment: Please read your error messages carefully. They tell a file and a line where the error happens. Please mark that place properly in your question. Check if my edit was done right with the information you have at hand. - Also what is is that you do not understand for the code that runs fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might expect, that the PHP engine will call `__isset()` before every access to **hidden** properties in PHP. But thats **not true**. Check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset):

> __isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.

So, that's expected behaviour, as only:

```
var_dump(isset($c->a));
```

will trigger `__isset()`.

All of the other lines will just trigger `__get()`. And as you didn't set those indexes it is expected behaviour.

Change your code to:

```
class c {
    public $x = array();
    public function __get($name) {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->x[$name];
    }
    public function __isset($name) {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return isset($this->x[$name]);
    }
}
```

to see which methods are actually called. This will give you:

```
c::__isset   <------ called!
bool(false)
c::__get

Notice: Undefined index: a in /tmp/a.php on line 6

Call Stack:
    0.0002     647216   1. {main}() /tmp/a.php:0
    0.0003     648472   2. c->__get() /tmp/a.php:16

<---------------------- not called 
bool(false)
c::__get

Notice: Undefined index: b in /tmp/a.php on line 6

Call Stack:
    0.0002     647216   1. {main}() /tmp/a.php:0
    0.0005     648656   2. c->__get() /tmp/a.php:17

<---------------------- not called     
bool(false)
c::__get

Notice: Undefined index: d in /tmp/a.php on line 6

Call Stack:
    0.0002     647216   1. {main}() /tmp/a.php:0
    0.0006     648840   2. c->__get() /tmp/a.php:18

<---------------------- not called     
bool(false)
```

Comment: Why would this be *expected* though? After all, if you remove both magic methods all warnings go away. And if you have them in, well -- why doesn't the compiler take advantage of `__isset` to conclude that since `$c->a` is not set then `$c->a->whatever` cannot possibly exist and stop before calling `__get`? IMHO this should be called a bug.

Comment: I cannot answer *why* the compiler does not calls `__isset`. I can just say *it does not* call it. Check my example to see. Check @Babas answer to see a workaround

Comment: Obviously it does not call it. But again, if you remove both magic methods there is no warning. Is it *expected* when you put them in? After all you did implement `__isset` correctly!

Comment: Note that you only have to remove `__get()` and the warnings will disappear. Do you see now?

Comment: It's very obvious *what* the compiler does. I am saying that *it is not correct (or at least it's surprising) that it does that*.

Comment: @Jon: This is expected because `__get` is called for all unset or invisible properties. That is by definition. http://php.net/__get *"The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope."*

Comment: This is not going anywhere.

Comment: @hek2mgl: `__isset` is called for the `isset` langauge construct, not for the read context of a property. That is the job of `__get`. This is why it is not called, it is just not used, because `__isset()` has not been designed for the magic operation of getting a property but for checking the existence of a property.

Comment: @hakre I know that. I've answered that ;)

Comment: @hakre: So you find it "normal" that providing a fully correct implementation of `__isset` is not enough to protect you from warnings, whereas a plain object with *no magic behavior at all* would have protected you?

Comment: @Jon: isset never issues a warning. so now back to earth, what is you issue? is the manual not clear about something? do you have a problem when implementing __get that you actually need to implement it? I don't get why you have such a hard time with that. It is totally uninteresting what I think normal is or not. When I use a language feature I have to take a look if it fits my needs or not and also to get it working as intended. Only because I want really traits (e.g. new MyClass with new SplFileInfo) it must not mean that these exists. so do you think it's "normal" PHP has none?

Comment: @hakre: `isset($c->a->b)` just caused a warning to be issued in the process of producing its return value, so I 'm not sure what exactly you mean by "never". As for the rest, I am only going to say that what you think normal or not is interesting to me by definition because I asked you. It's fine if you don't care to answer, but we don't really need the condescending tone.

Comment: @Jon, when you implement __get() you need to implement it. In your example not isset issued a warning but the implementation of __get, specifically this line: `$this->x[$name];`. See the subtle difference? The one is straight isset operation, the other is invoking a function and while doing so, executes standard PHP code with standard warnings / notices. It's not protection you ask for but disabling of warnings and notices. IMHO this would not be good because undefined indexes notices would go unnoticed.

Comment: @hakre: I edited my comment above just seconds ago to make the wording technically correct, which leaves you responding to something else (sorry for that). So, having closed the "`isset` didn't do it, the bad `__get` did it", what now? I am interested in the observable behavior of `isset`. When I see `isset(...)` I want to feel safe that there will be no warnings. And the compiler can do this. Why does it choose not to?

Comment: @Jon: Well, as usual: Magic makes things hard to debug. I normally suggest to stay away from these. so if you want observable behavior of isset, you need to implement it. E.g. doing index checks in __get before just accessing. It's your implementation, so do it the way you need it. -or- do not implement __get then you don't have the problem as well. Another example: Just throw an Exception in __get - before you do anything else. Just for the freaking fun. And then put that code somewhere in. you do not even need to use isset to demonstrate that something is not observable any longer in magic.

Comment: @Jon I guess you have something like `Iterator::valid()` in mind, which is called before `Iterator::current()` in foreach loops. I can understand what you have in mind. But you just have to read the documentation. There is no *auto __isset() on property access*. It's just not implemented in PHP. (and I don't want to have it)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Well, [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50813) and the few votes it has prove that I 'm not the only one who thinks this is a bug. And does the answer from the PHP dev mean that they actually agreed and so tried to fix it?

Comment: Note that reporting a bug is open for all. This reporter and the commenters seems to not have read the documentation ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Right. So if `echo "format"` formats your hard disk, the only one at fault is you. After all, the documentation said that if you do that it would actually format the disk. Being technically correct does not make something *good*. It only makes it *undisputable*. I am interested in *good*.

Comment: @Jon: It's not that I could not understand what you aim for, but on the other hand I do not see that this is actually a flaw. Having a more indirect implementation in PHP must not mean it's automatically a better one. It would leave less flexibility in using the magic methods because they would not be that magic any longer. You would have less control (what you coin "protect me"). If we do the magic, we don't want protection, we actually want this as much open as possible. To exploit the most (it's not enough for everything but still).

Comment: @hakre: "Less flexibility" and "not that magic any longer" are words without code to back them. I 'm actually proposing more magic, not less. But let's not argue, IMHO it would be better to focus the energy into a patch for this. Thanks for the conversation!

Comment: @Jon: If you don't want to argue please accept there is nothing to patch :) But I won't stop you, it's free software you can change it for your compile. But I think you're just scratching an itch. I do not see any issue here honestly.

Comment: @hakre: "If you don't want to argue please admit I 'm right". I preferred your initial reply better. :-) Agree that it's a non-issue in practice. Now if only all of PHP's bugs were like that...

Answer (score 2):

You have a poorly implemented `__get`

```
$c = new c();
var_dump(isset($c->a)); // false
var_dump(isset($c->a->b)); // false
var_dump(isset($c->b->c)); // false
var_dump(isset($c->d['e'])); // false


class c {
    public $x = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($name) ? $this->x[$name] : null;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->x[$name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree. The main reason `__isset` exists is exactly so you don't have to do that in `__get`.

Comment: @Jon. The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) says: `__isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.` That's all, nothing more

Comment: `__isset` has done its job the values are totally out of the current object scope by calling `$c->b->c` you can calling object `b` which may have not implemented isset ..... please check the doc

Comment: @Baba: But you are **not** calling `$c->b->c`. You are calling `isset($c->b->c)`, which is a huge difference in PHP. For example, `$a = array(); echo $a['foo']; echo isset($a['foo']);`. `isset()` does not produce a warning, that's why we have it.

Comment: if you are calling `$c->b->c->e->f` or `$c->b->c` it does not matter the document is clear `__isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.` it would only check `$c->b` every other depends on the values which might not even be a object

Comment: The compiler sees `isset($c->a->b)`. It treats this code as `isset($c->__get('a')->b)`. **Why does it not treat it like `isset($c->a) ? isset($c->__get('a')->b) : false`**? After all, it can easily choose to do that and the resulting behavior will not be surprising -- it will be the same as if `$c` were a vanilla object.

Comment: @Jon I would advice you to take a couple of minutes and play around with the code. It's **totally** clear was going on

Comment: @Baba: What is obvious is that while I am asking the thought-provoking question *why do A when you can do B that is better* you are copy/pasting the answer "because the manual says to do A". And even that is debatable.